# Why can't modify the nestState directly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In [redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) I see this:

> #### Common Mistake #1: New variables that point to the same objects
>
> Defining a new variable does not create a new actual object - it only creates another reference to the same object. An example of this error would be:

```
function updateNestedState(state, action) {
    let nestedState = state.nestedState;

    // ERROR: this directly modifies the existing object reference - don't do this!
    nestedState.nestedField = action.data;

    return {
        ...state,
        nestedState
    };
}
```

> This function does correctly return a shallow copy of the top-level state object, but because the `nestedState` variable was still pointing at the existing object, the state was directly mutated.

But we know that `combineReducers` just judge the state change by the top-level reference.See redux [comBindReducer.js src](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.js):

```
let hasChanged = false
const nextState = {}

for (let i = 0; i < finalReducerKeys.length; i++) {
  const key = finalReducerKeys[i]
  const reducer = finalReducers[key]
  const previousStateForKey = state[key]
  const nextStateForKey = reducer(previousStateForKey, action)

  if (typeof nextStateForKey === 'undefined') {
    const errorMessage = getUndefinedStateErrorMessage(key, action)
    throw new Error(errorMessage)
  }

  nextState[key] = nextStateForKey
  hasChanged = hasChanged || nextStateForKey !== previousStateForKey
}

return hasChanged ? nextState : state
```

It just access every reducer and judge whether the state reference changed.

So back to the question,the retured object reference is changed,so the the `hasChanged` variable is true,and redux works fine.So I don't know what's the side effect of state was directly?

If you know,please tell me,thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that the example is directly related to `cobmineReducers`. I believe that it attempts to present a caveat related to immutability: whenever a value inside a complex object changes, the entire hierarchy should indicate that. So if `state.nestedState.nestedField` changes, it means that `state.nestedState` has changed, and so did `state`. It should be enough to look at `state` or at `nestedState` to realize that `nestedField` has changed.

Developers who are new to this concept, may often think that assigning `state.nestedState` to a new variable and then changing it is fine, but it's not, because `a === state.nestedState` is still `true`.

`combineReducers` only cares if one of the slices has changed. If the rule above is followed, it will "work fine". But what happens if we look directly at `state.nestedState`? the reference is still the same, so it doesn't work anymore.

When it comes to React, [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/connect.js) works in the same way. It shallow compares the props, relying on the same rule: no need to deep compare, because the parent should indicate if the child has changed.

Back to your question: **what are the side effects of changing the state directly?**
Let's use your example:

```
// reducer.js
function reducer(state, action) {
   let nestedState = state.nestedState;
   nestedState.nestedField = action.data;
   return {
       ...state,
       nestedState
   };
}
```

This will work fine:

```
connect(state => ({ state }))(MyComponent)
```

This will not:

```
connect(state => ({ nestedState: state.nestedState }))(MyComponent)
```

I hope it answers your question, or at least sheds some light on it.

Comment: As the author of that Redux docs page: yep, that's what I was getting at.  If the `nestedState` field is directly mutated instead of swapped out, and then a `mapState` function returns that `nestedState` value, `connect` will see that the reference is the same as before, think that nothing has changed, and not actually re-render the component.

Comment: @OB3 Thanks for your reply,I don't think it from the point of react-redux.Now I get it.